# Solve the equation $u_t+xtu_x=x^2$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the equation $ u_t + xtu_x = x ^ 2 $ with the initial condition $ u (x, 0) = \varphi (x) $, where $ \varphi $ is a function of class $ \mathcal {C} ^ 1 ( \mathbb R) $.

**My try:**

I divide by $ x $ and I have that $$\dfrac 1 x u_t+tu_x=x$$
Then, $$\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{t}\Rightarrow \int t\ \text{d}t=\int 1/x\ \text{d}x\Rightarrow t^2-2\ln(x)=k.$$
Now if $ v (w, z) = u (x, 0) $, then $$\begin{cases}
 w=t^2-2\ln(x) \\ 
 z=t.
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
 x=e^{-1/2(w-z^2)} \\ 
 z=t.
\end{cases}$$

I don't know what else to do, and I don't know if what I have is good, I stagnate. Any help to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_t+xtu_x=x^2$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{xt}=\frac{du}{x^2}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{xt}$ :
$$x^2e^{t^2}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{x^2}$ with $x^2=c_1e^{-t^2}$ :

$c_1e^{-t^2}dt=du \quad\implies\quad u=c_1\int_0^t e^{-\tau^2}d\tau+c_2$
$$u-c_1\int_0^t e^{-\tau^2}d\tau=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u-c_1\int_0^t e^{-\tau^2}d\tau=F(c_1)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the initial condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=x^2e^{t^2}\int_0^t e^{-\tau^2}d\tau+F\left(x^2e^{t^2}\right)}$$
CONDITION : $u(x,0)=\varphi(x)$

$u(x,0)=x^2e^{0}\int_0^0 e^{-\tau^2}d\tau+F\left(x^2e^{0}\right)=F(x^2)$
$$F(x^2)=\varphi(x)$$
Let $x^2=X$
$$F(X)=\varphi(X^{1/2})$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x^2e^{t^2}$ then $X^{1/2}=xe^{t^2/2}$  and $F(x^2e^{t^2})= \varphi(xe^{t^2/2})$ :
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=x^2e^{t^2}\int_0^t e^{-\tau^2}d\tau+\varphi(xe^{t^2/2})}$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}x^2e^{t^2}\text{erf}(t)+\varphi(xe^{t^2/2})$$